# Value error: cannot reindex an axis with duplicated labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, label

I'm having a little issue with a code:

I'm trying to create new columns on an existing df with some other df with % for different stock tickers as index. These tickers can repeat since one index can have more than one %, and the values can repeat too.

So my problem is that I can create new columns with a "df2", which has repeated indices and repeated values (even for the same index), but for some reason I cannot do that with a "df3" with the same structure. Then, I can do it again with a "df4" but not with a "df5".

Again, these "df2", "df3", "df4", "df5", etc, are basically the same df's and have the same length, have repeated indices, repeated values, etc.
I cannot print the df's because it's confidential, but here's the code.

To end this questions, df1,df2,df3 and df4 have the same indices in the same order, with different values but have repeated of everything.

```
df['new column 1'] = df1  # (This one works)
df['new column 2'] = df2  # (This one doesn't)
df['new column 3'] = df3  # (This one works)
df['new column 4'] = df4  # (This one doesn't)
```

Comment: If your data is confidential, please provide a reproducible minimal dummy example

Answer (score 0):

You can try to keep only one instance of index:

```
df['new column 2'] = df2[~df2.index.duplicated()]
```

Comment: Hi, that code drops duplicated, which I must not do. I have 4500 datapoints that repeats themeselves but i still need every one of them. All my df's have that length (4500)